# Pi zero w and pitft plus 2.8 in and justboom amp zero phat

Tags: pi-zero-w, pitft, compatibility

I need help determining if these two devices are compatible on the raspberry pi zero w at the same time. I just got the adafruit pitft plus 2.8

https://www.adafruit.com/product/2298

Site says pins used are SCK MOSI MISO CE0 CE1 Gpio 25,24 It also uses gpio pins 23,22,21,18 for the buttons from what I read somewhere else. Idk if it's possible to change those pins but I can remove the buttons if I must. I would prefer not to though.

and I want to get the just boom amp zero phat

https://www.justboom.co/product/justboom-amp-zero-phat/

I can only find the pinout on pinoutxyz.com and idk if it's even right. I was hoping someone could try and help me figure out if these two devices are compatible together. I have googled this it's just that as far as I know the just boom amp zero phat is relatively new to the scene and this is also my first raspberry pi build. I've done much with Arduino since I'm in college for engineering and I've used a raspberry pi before but I've never actually compiled a list of components to build something on my own. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question over and over again.

Comment: I didn't. I changed the wording so what I'm asking is more precise. I changed my wording and provided more details. So what if they're the same details it's a different question

Comment: I'm going to ask it again maybe I'll get a chance to get a response now that you know it's a different question.

Comment: If you wish to edit your original question, then edit that.   And please be civil.

Comment: I did edit it!!! Maybe if you'd read it

Comment: By "edit your original question" I do not mean re-write it and ask it again.  I mean, edit your original question.  There is an `edit` link below it for that purpose (in the row with "mod share edit close delete flag").

Comment: I'm on Android and I've never posted on the raspberry pi stack exchange so when you closed the question the option to edit went away. I can no longer edit the question, hence my reposting.

Comment: By "original question" I meant your original question, not this one: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/83900/5538

Comment: That was the first time I asked it. That is my original question. And I did edit it in both instances of the posts.

Comment: Reread my question that i already edited in the very first post with the question in it and you'll find that it answers the very question you asked me about being more specific. I have specified in both instances of the question. Please actually read what I am asking in stead of assuming I am blowing you off.

Comment: Alright, sorry.  There were no edits showing on either question; if you look at [the revision history](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/83900/revisions), it appears as if the last paragraph that starts with "Edit" was part of the original version.  Something is wrong with that. The reason it then shows me as having edited it is I clicked on edit and didn't change anything -- although it says "22 characters added", if you look at the side-by-side markdown view it shows no changes. O_o? Usually the interface works fine, lol...

Comment: ...Anyway, if your original question is the way you want it, then there's no problem (?)